# Django 1.11 - forms.Models: change default form widget for DateTimeField

Tags: python, django

I have a data field

```
missing_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=False)
```

The default django form widget is to use TextInput, and it is not displaying as Calendar Date/Time select as in the admin page.

Can you please advise how can I display the Calendar Date/Time like below:
[Calendar date/time Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSbha.png)

It is really appreciated with your help.

Thanks
Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to include any more of your code. i.e. Have you created a forms.py file? I presume you will be creating ModelForms?

If you have you can do something like this:

```
from django.forms import widget
Class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

Class Example(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta: #insert class Meta below
         model = #reference your model
         fields = () #include fields you want to display from your model
         widgets = {
               'missing_date': Date_Input()
         }
```

Comment: Thanks GraceBe for your answer. I used django.forms.widget and it worked for me as well.

Comment: glad I could help.