# Django 1.11 - ModelForm: change default form widget for DateTimeField

Tags: django, forms, model, datepicker

I need some help in rendering a datetime picker in my form insead of the default text field that is displayed. I am using Django 1.11 and have followed the recent solution posted here: [Django 1.11 - forms.Models: change default form widget for DateTimeField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792930/django-1-11-forms-models-change-default-form-widget-for-datetimefield/46718857#46718857) however

I receive errors when using the same code.
The first error I receive is: cannot import name 'widget'. I can pass this error by importing 'widgets' instead. Has this been renamed?

The second error I receive after renaming to widgets is NameError: name 'forms' is not defined. I can pass this error by changing the code to: 
`Class DateInput(widgets.DateInput):`
Is this the correct treatment for this error?

The third error I receive is: NameError: name 'Date_Input' is not defined I can pass this error by changing the final piece of code (removing underscore in Date_Input) above to:

```
widgets = {
            'missing_date': DateInput()
        }
```

After these changes, I no longer get any errors however the date field in my form is still rendering as a text field and not as a date picker.

Can anyone shed any further light on the solution above and why it possibly isn't working for me?

Additionally I would like to modify the solution mentioned in the link above to render a `datetime` picker not just date picker, but I first wanted to test the functionality using the code from the previous post solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by splitting the datetime into seperate fields of date and time and using the following code in forms.py:

```
class TimeInput(forms.TimeInput):
    input_type = 'time'

class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
```

and within my ModelForm Class:

```
    widgets = {
        'start_date': DateInput(),
        'start_time': TimeInput(),
        'end_date': DateInput(),
        'end_time': TimeInput(),
    }
```